# How to prevent losing JDBC connection to Redshift during long query on Windows 10

Tags: amazon-web-services, jdbc, amazon-redshift

I am using the Redshift 4.1 1013 JDBC driver on Windows 10. When I submit a query from SQL Workbench or Aginity and that query takes longer than 2 minutes  the application loses connectivity with the query such that when the query completes the applications are not notified.

I have followed the AWS instructions for setting the registry keys and changing ICMP setting on my VPC.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-drop-issues.html#configure-custom-icmp

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-firewall-guidance.html

My MTU is 1500.

What other options can I try to keep my queries from disconnecting? Is there a local firewall setting I must apply?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Stephen.

Comment: The registry key changes... do they require a reboot (and did you)?  What about setting `TCPKeepAliveMinutes` in the [DSN](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-jdbc-options.html)?  2 minutes is an unexpectedly short time, though. I would expect 15 if it's a keepalive issue.

Comment: I did not configure it because they said doing so at the DNS level was optional if you set it globally. I will investigate how to configure at the DNS level. Do you happen to have an example of your DNS settings I can borrow from?

Comment: I'm a DBA, not a Java developer, but check the link on the word "DSN" in my prior comment.  It looks like you could just append `&` (if you have other parameters) or `?` (if you don't), followed by something like `tcpKeepAlive=true&TCPKeepAliveMinutes=1` to the end.  I've definitely seen connections go unexpectedly unresponsive or closed on one side with the other side unaware, in AWS, when keepalives are not enabled, which is why I suspect this to be your problem.

Comment: Thank  you. Do you happen to know how to configure this in an ODBC driver?